# Can't free some memory in C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I am working on a Hash Table C program. And I have just 1 memory leak in the following function:

```
void put(char *key, char *value, TD* H)
{
    if(!get(key, H))
    {
        int poz = fd(key, H->M);
        CelulaH *aux, *aux2;
        aux = malloc(sizeof(CelulaH));
        aux->key = malloc(50);
        aux->value = malloc(50);
        strcpy(aux->key, key);
        strcpy(aux->value, value);

        if(H->v[poz] == NULL)
        {
            H->v[poz] = (TCelulaG*)malloc(sizeof(TCelulaG));
            H->v[poz]->info = malloc(sizeof(CelulaH));
            memcpy(H->v[poz]->info, aux, sizeof(CelulaH));
            H->v[poz]->urm = NULL;
        }
        else
            InsLGO(&H->v[poz], aux, sizeof(CelulaH), cmp);

        //if(aux)
            free(aux);
    }
}
```

I have three structures : TD, CelulaH, TCelulaG. This is how they look:

```
typedef struct celula
{
    struct celula* urm;
    void* info;
} TCelulaG, *TLG, **ALG;


typedef struct
{
    size_t M;
    TFhash fd;
    TLG *v;
} TD;


typedef struct
{
    char *key, *value;
} CelulaH;
```

And this is the output of the Valgrind:

```
==5380== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5380==    at 0x8048A2B: get (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x8048B26: put (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x8048E19: CitireComenzi (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x804909E: main (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380== 
==5380== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5380==    at 0x8048BB7: put (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x8048E19: CitireComenzi (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x804909E: main (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380== 
==5380== 50 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==5380==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5380==    by 0x8048B60: put (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x8048E19: CitireComenzi (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x804909E: main (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380== 
==5380== 50 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==5380==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==5380==    by 0x8048B73: put (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x8048E19: CitireComenzi (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==    by 0x804909E: main (in /home/luzi/TemaSD/tema1)
==5380==
```

So the only problem it seems to be now is the two mallocs in the "put" function. All the other mallocs from the program are free'd so this is the only ones left to free. Any ideas?

Comment: "I have just one memory leak" ... that you are aware of!

Answer (score 2):

```
aux = malloc(sizeof(CelulaH));
aux->key = malloc(50);
aux->value = malloc(50);
```

Then you need to free them all.

> In order to overcome memory leak you need to `free()` all memory
>   allocated using `malloc()` `calloc()` and `realloc()`

```
free(aux->value);
free(aux->key);
free(aux);
```

Comment: I've already tried this but on multiple calls of the "put function" it will turn into double free's or corruptions. I need to make somehow to free only at the very last call in order to free the memo where I stack up the "key" and "value". I think the problem is my poor coding style.

Answer (score 0):

A structure can also be used in a malloc statement.

You can allocate memory on structure like that:

```
/* Allocate memory */
aux = (CelulaH*)malloc(sizeof(CelulaH));
/* Use variables */
strcpy((*aux).key, key);
strcpy((*aux).value, value);
```

and then just free it

```
free(aux);
```